# php glob() retrieve all files except one

Tags: php

I have a folder named 'Folder'. There are several photos inside it.
One of them is "1.jpg"..
I need to retrieve all the photos from this folder, except "1.jpg" ($first)..
As I understand, I need something like if ($image=$first) { . . . } inside of `foreach.`

```
 $first="1.jpg";
 $dirname="folder";
 $images = glob($dirname.'*');

 foreach($images as $image) {
 $html="<img src='".$image."'><br />";
 echo $html;
 }
```

Thanks for attention

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can skip the `echo` when `$image` is not equal (!=) to `$first`:

```
foreach($images as $image) {
    if ($image != $first) {
        $html="<img src='".$image."'><br />";
        echo $html;
    }
}
```

Or you can use [continue](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.continue.php) to skip to the next image, when `$image` is equal to `$first`, if you have more complex code in the foreach:

```
foreach($images as $image) {
    if ($image == $first) {
        continue;
    }
    $html="<img src='".$image."'><br />";
    echo $html;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I used != approach ;)

Answer (score 0):

```
$first="1.jpg";
$dirname="folder";
$images = glob($dirname.'*');
unset($images[$first]);
foreach($images as $image) {
     echo "<img src='".$image."'><br />";
}
```